# In Java, why does the decimal separator follow the Locale's language, not its country, and, more importantly, how does one override it?

Tags: java, locale, number-formatting, decimal-point

I'm working on an international project and have observed that, in Java, the choice of the decimal separator is based on the Locale's language, not its country. For example:

```
DecimalFormat currencyFormatter = (DecimalFormat) NumberFormat.getInstance(new Locale("it","IT"));
System.out.println(currencyFormatter.format(-123456.78));

currencyFormatter = (DecimalFormat) NumberFormat.getInstance(new Locale("en","IT"));
System.out.println(currencyFormatter.format(-123456.78));
```

produces the following output:

```
-123.456,78
-123,456.78
```

I would have expected it to follow the country, since if I'm in the country, whether I speak English or Italian the numbers in that country are written with the decimal separator as comma.

My question is two-fold:

1. Does anyone know why this behaviour follows the language?
2. More importantly, can anyone offer details as to how to modify the default behaviour in Java to follow the language instead?

Thanks.

Comment: 2) you mean "to follow the country instead" don't you?

Comment: It seems reasonable to me that the decimal separator convention follows the language of a document, not the country which the document is currently in. But it would be interesting to hear people's opinions on this. At least I know that my English professors would have disliked me using Swedish conventions for writing dates, numbers, etc. in English coursework.

Comment: A Locale defines a set of cultural conventions for common aspects present in every language and its variations. A country defines variations on a language (i.e. English used in Britain and US) but country does not mark in any case a common convention to be applicable to its languages (in Canada, there's English en_CA and French fr_CA). And by the way, there's no culture that uses English as a language in Italy, consider using plainly Locale("en"), that's why that Locale en_IT falls to plain "en".
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_and_time_notation_in_Canada <- interesting about this topic

Answer (score 6):

It is very, very likely that there is no known "en_IT" locale on your system and that Java knows of no such locale.

Therefore you'll get the resources for the closest matching Locale, as per this note in the [JavaDoc of `Locale`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html):

> When you ask for a resource for a particular locale, you get back the best available match, not necessarily precisely what you asked for. For more information, look at [`ResourceBundle`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html).

The [relevant documentation in `ResourceBundle`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html#getBundle(java.lang.String,%20java.util.Locale,%20java.lang.ClassLoader)) shows that the country alone is never attempted as the identifier to find a given resource. Only the language, the language + the country and the language + the country + the variant are used.

Comment: -1 : Unfortunately this doesn't help to the second part of the question: *can anyone offer details as to how to modify the default behavior in Java to follow the country instead?*

Comment: +1, this is the correct answer. There *is* no `en-it` locale. If you have no support for `xx-yy` locale, then use `xx`. You can't "fall-forward" to Italy; `IT` doesn't *have* a locale. Switzerland has 3 locales: **French** (`fr-ch`), **German** (`de-ch`), and **Italian** (`it-ch`). You can't "fall-forward" to *Swiss*, there is no such language as "Swiss". If you asked for `en-ch` (English-Switzerland), Java can't fallforward to `ch`. Switzerland doesn't *have* a locale. You asked for a variant of English that i don't recognize; but i can at least still give you English.

Comment: But to answer the 2nd part of the posters question: Enumerate the available locales and choose the one you desire. If `en-IT` is not available, and you want an english speaker in Italy to be forced to read Italian, then fallback to `it-it` yourself. And if you want an english speaker in Kurwait (`en-kw`) to have to read arabic, then use `ar-kw` instead.

Answer (score 4):

But if you are an Englishman living in Italy, chances are you still write your numbers the English way and count your money in pounds inside your head - and vice versa ;-)

So to me this behaviour looks perfectly logical. And I am afraid there may not be a way to get what you want :-(

**Update based on the comment of Oscar Reyes:** In Java 6, NumberFormatProvider enables you to achieve your goal.

Comment: +1. Formatting numbers is a matter of language, not of where you are.

Comment: But for a software system wouldn't you want to format the currency always according to the country's currency?

Comment: @chenson42 Well I can only speak for myself with certainty. Having been living in Spain, Finland and India apart from my native Hungary, still I always preferred to see numbers, date and time on my computer screen the Hungarian style, not the local way. An OS or a personal app is quite different in this respect of course, than e.g. an ERP or financial application. But guess which one is used by more people...

Comment: @OregonGhost Formating numbers is a matter of where you are. Two countries with the same official language may format numbers differently. For example, in South Africa, the comma is used as the decimal in english.

Comment: @cquezel: I see what you mean, but it's still language: If I'm in South Africa and using a German locale, e.g. because I'm writing a letter to Germany, I'm still formatting numbers like Germans. What you refer to is the difference in locales e.g. between en-ZA and en-US, but that is still a matter of language. en-ZA is not English, it is "English as written in South Africa", just like en-US is "English as written in the USA", which are different locales and different languages (with a lot in common). They are tied to a region, but it still does not matter if you're actually in that region.

Answer (score 4):

> 1.- Does anyone know why this behaviour follows the language?

One of the first aspects that change in an application according to its locale is the language. Think of Switzerland, where they have both French and German as official languages. Using the country in this scenario makes no sense because, besides currency there are other aspect ( such as display messages, to take into consideration )

Same goes for a number of countries ( Canada is other that comes to my mind).

The country is an option to specialize that language.

Since there is no "Italian English" en_IT doesn't make much sense. So it takes "english" and that's why the returned instance is the one with "en" English.

> 2.- More importantly, can anyone offer details as to how to modify the default behavior in Java to follow the language instead?

You mean, the country right?

The answer is in the method: [NumberFormat.getAvailableLocales()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#getAvailableLocales%28%29) which in turn leads you to: [NumberFormatProvider](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/spi/NumberFormatProvider.html) which is an abstract class you can extend to return the correct `NumberFormat` for "en_IT"  ( which pretty much will return it_IT )

<strike>How to install that new class goes beyond my knowledge, but I think you'll have to hack it somewhere in the `jre` directory.</strike>

**EDIT**

As I suspect the class should be installed under `jre/ext` folder and that's it.

There is a project somewhere else which did something similar to support "gl_ES" ( Galician )

Here's instructions on how to install it and what it is all about:

http://www.javagalician.org/install.html

So, basically, if you want to provide a bunch of instances for Italy ( or even better a single one ) , you just have to create one instance of the NumberFormatProvider and have it responding all the languages available.

Answer (score 2):

Modifying all of Java is a big order; as far as I know, there's no way to do this at the JVM level.  However, you can manually set the number format for your particular classes/projects to pretty much any locale (or even imaginary system) with the [DecimalFormatSymbols class](http://java.sun.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormatSymbols.html).  See "Altering the Formatting Symbols" at the [Java Tutorials page on format customization](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/i18n/format/decimalFormat.html) for examples and more information.

Granted, this is not an optimal approach if your program might be used in more than three or four different locations, but it could work if you're only supporting a few.

Answer (score 2):

Your assumption *"I would have expected it to follow the country, since if I'm in the country, whether I speak English or Italian the numbers in that country are written with the decimal separator as comma."* is wrong. Several bilingual countries have language specific formatting rules for numbers. Among the countries with formatting rules in Sun's JDK, this applies to Canada, India and Luxembourg.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be able to override the NumberFormat behavior per Locale using [LocaleServiceProvider](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/spi/LocaleServiceProvider.html).  This would require Java 6 though ...

Answer (score 0):

> I would have expected it to follow the country, since if I'm in the country, whether I speak English or Italian the numbers in that country are written with the decimal separator as comma.

No. Some countries with many official languages such as Canada (two official languages) have different formatting convention based on the language:

```
-1 234,56 (Locale.CANADA_FRENCH)
-1,234.56 (Locale.CANADA (should probably be named CANADA_ENGLISH))
```

Answer (score 0):

As people have noted, the problem is most likely that java can't find your exact local, so it went to what it thought was closest.  If you do have a DecimalFormat object, you can manually change the separators if you'd like.

```
DecimalFormat format = ...;
DecimalFormatSymbols symbols = format.getDecimalFormatSymbols();
symbols.setDecimalSeparator(',');
symbols.setGroupingSeparator('.');
format.setDecimalFormatSymbols(symbols);
```